# Apache Nifi - how to write Json to a database table column?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have an json array that I need to write to a database (as text).

I have two options:

1. Write as an array of objects, so the field would contain [{},{},{}]
2. Write each record as an object, so the field would contain {}

The problem is that nifi does not know how to map the json object to a specific database field on PutDatabaseRecord.

How to I map it?

Here is my flow:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use a combination of
ConvertAvroToJSON >> SplitJson(if you have multiple) >> ConvertJsontoSQL >> PutSQL

In the convertJsonToSQL you will have to set the db,schema,table for the incoming json payload to map to.
The config options are self explainatory for the convertJsonToSQL processor
[image]